# Use Loop in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Good evening. So, can you guys give me some examples of how i can use a loop to make this function smaller, I'm not acquainted to Loop in JS. Thanks :)

```
function setValue(){

                let in1 = document.querySelector("#number1")
                let in2 = document.querySelector("#number2")
                let in3 = document.querySelector("#number3")
                let in4 = document.querySelector("#number4")
                let in5 = document.querySelector("#number5")
                let in6 = document.querySelector("#number6")
                let in7 = document.querySelector("#number7")
                let in8 = document.querySelector("#number8")
                let in9 = document.querySelector("#number9")
                let in10 = document.querySelector("#number10")

                setAttribute('marginLeft', in1.value)
                setAttribute('marginRight', in2.value)
                setAttribute('marginBottom', in3.value)
                setAttribute('marginTop', in4.value)
                setAttribute('margin', in5.value)
                setAttribute('paddingLeft', in6.value)
                setAttribute('paddingRight', in7.value)
                setAttribute('paddingBottom', in8.value)
                setAttribute('paddingTop', in9.value)
                setAttribute('padding', in10.value)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of IDs, and have an array of the attributes you need to set:

```
function setValue() {
  const attributeNames = ['marginLeft', 'marginRight', 'marginBottom', ...];
  document.querySelectorAll('.numbers').forEach((elm, i) => {
    setAttribute(attributeNames[i], elm.value);
  });
}
```

If you can't depend on `NodeList.forEach` existing (it's not that old, so isn't supported on old browsers), polyfill it first:

```
if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

(or change it to a `for` loop, or `.call` `Array.prototype.forEach`)